# Deny Execute Access on Removable drives (Windows XP)

Tags: windows-xp, group-policy, removable

I have my old computer with "**Windows XP**" on it. I was thinking if I could prevent the execution of .EXE .BAT .VBS and .LNK on Removable Devices. I can't find "**Deny Execute Access**" on Group Policy. Is there any possible ways to prevent it. I don't like using any antivirus on my old PC.

Comment: if you are worried about things autorunning from removable devices, try disabling the autorun of removable drives. http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-prevent-a-usb-drive-from-running-anything-automatically-in-windows/

Comment: I already disabled autorun on my PC but my brother keeps on plugging usb with shortcuts(.lnk ) in it.

Comment: If someone could answer this. I could also fix someone's computer cause they are careless to execute those shortcut files and other viruses.

Comment: There's really no answer anywhere else on superuser, or from a web search? XP came out like 15 years ago, did you search?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my own question basing it from http://www.mechbgon.com/srp/index.html#setup

BUT you would have to manually assign drive letters to block the execution from the list of executable file extensions. And I think this is it. Since this OS is old enough I don't really need to take much time fixing it. If you find a better answer you may post it here.

Here's what I did.
[image]

[image]

Comment: From what I can see on the screenshots, it should be working just fine. Isn't it?

Comment: yep, after making any changes, you have to Refresh Group Policy settings with GPUpdate.exe or simply restart your computer.